# How can I keep input events from propagating to siblings of a grid?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I have a page of my Windows Phone 8 app. the page has a root grid and in it, it has a has a Grid element containing the normal controls of the page. The root grid also has a usercontrol in it. Both the Grid and the usercontrol are in 0,0 in the root grid. Now the problem is that when I make the usercontrol visible and use it to display some "please wait" information, the other grid that holds all of the normal controls of the app still gets touch input.

The whole idea is that a lengthy operations causes the usercontrol to show up with a translucent background and a message to please wait. I want to somehow set it up to capture all input but nothing works.

Here is the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.ProgressPopup" ...>
    <Grid Name="ContentArea" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Margin="0" ManipulationStarted="ContentArea_ManipulationStarted"
          Tap="ContentArea_Tap"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="ContentArea_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Rectangle Opacity="0.85" Name="TheBackground" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Fill="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <ProgressBar Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" x:Name="ProgressBar"
                     IsIndeterminate="{Binding bIsIndeterminate}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" 
                     Height="12" Margin="0,-30,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock ... />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is how it is used on the page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="AirMobility.Pages.MainPage"
    ... >

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0" x:Name="PageStuff">
            ...
        </Grid>

        <usercontrols:ProgressPopup Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="WaitScreen" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

When the usercontrol called "WaitScreen" becomes visible, the "PageStuff" grid and the controls in it still get input. Inside of that grid is a pivot control and the pages of the pivot control can still be scrolled. I tried to get ManipulationStarted events and set e.handler=true to stop propagation but it doesn't work. Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how to handle this in the usercontrol or in the definition of the usercontrol in the page xaml? I just don't want to have to somehow add a bunch of event handlers on each page that has one of these "WaitScreen" usercontrols.

[EDIT...]

I tried this variation of the usercontrol and it still does not work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.ProgressPopup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}">

    <Grid Name="ContentArea" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Background="#01808080">
        <Grid Name="TheBackground" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#80204080"/>
        <ProgressBar Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" x:Name="ProgressBar"
            IsIndeterminate="{Binding bIsIndeterminate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="12" Margin="0,-30,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Text="{Binding Text}" MinWidth="200" TextAlignment="Center"
            Opacity="1" Margin="0,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40" FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}}" FontFamily="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The underlying pivot can still move.

Comment: After adding the tap event handler, it looks like taps are not passed through.  The only symptom remaining is that the pivot control under the usercontrol can still be dragged/swiped to change pages.

Answer (score 1):

If the WaitScreen is Transparent, the touch events can go through.

**Big Edit to put the overlay in the PopupControl**

1. I advise you to add an overlayGrid **inside** the usercontrol, but **under** the content of the  Usercontrol - **order matters**.

That control is **semi transparent** ( `Background="#80204080"` ) so it should catch mouse events and not let them flow behind.

```
<UserControl x:Class="..." ... />
    <Grid x:Name="popupLayoutRoot">
        <Grid x:Name="overlayGrid" Background="#80204080" />
        <Grid x:Name="visiblePopupContent"  
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock  Text="Action in progress..."                               
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

overlayGrid and visiblePopupContent must not be parent and child but siblings.

2. Make the `Usercontrol` visible when the Waitscreen  is visible :

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0" x:Name="PageStuff">
        </Grid>
        <usercontrols:ProgressPopup Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="WaitScreen" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Here is link to full working solution : http://1drv.ms/1lm6jwN

Regards

Comment: I need to keep all of the ProgressPopup code and XAML inside of the ProgressPopup in order to reuse it on any page at any time. With this change, I end up needing to add more code to every page that uses the popup.

Plus, it didn't work. I even made if visible to start with and I could still drag the pivot control contents. But it was a good idea.

Comment: Just made a big edit to make the UserControl reusable

Comment: @David, so is it useful for you ?

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. I agree that it SHOULD solve the problem but placing any Grid of any opacity does not block the pivot control from accepting and acting on dragging gestures. Since I cannot tap on a button and have that work, I suspect that something strange is going on in the OS. Even the Grid element on the page itself, not in the usercontrol, did not hide gestures from the underlying pivot control!

Comment: David, for me it works perfectly with a Pivot Control under. I have edited my post to put a link to a working solution. There is button in the main page to display the usercontrol for 2s or 3s. During that time, no possible gesture or click to the pivot. Watch it. I 'll be so happy you tell me it works.

Comment: Yes, yours works. My project targets Windows Phone 8.0. I will continue to investigate but your effort is worth at least an up-vote.

Comment: Actually I made exactly the same thing to work under WP8.0. I won't make the effort of rewriting for WP8.0, I let you do it. It's only the matter of creating again the project under WP8.0, copying the content of MainWindow and creating the Usercontrol (10mn).

Comment: I added more to my original question. It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Here's a video of it failing for me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TBeqKKDHP8
This uses the colors that you used to show that I did use your code.  This is definitely a weird problem but one that I can't keep working on due to this being for my job and I need to move on. I'll just use the IsHittestVisible=false setting for the pivot. Thanks for so much help though. I wish I had time to just start from scratch to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I added an email address to my profile. Send me an email if you want me to send you ALL of the code. Maybe I'm missing something somewhere less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add another <Grid> element on the page itself, not in the usercontrol, to cover the Pivot Control at all times. I hard coded it to have a background color of #80ff0000 and through the pink, I could still move the Pivot Control.

My solution, which violates the desire to keep all of the popup code within the popup, involved setting IsHittestVisible=false for the pivot control while the wait screen is visible. This is not ideal because other pages don't use a pivot control and therefore need a page-specific "ShowWaitScreen()" method. I don't like code redundancy but this will ahve to do for now.

I think that the Pivot Control is getting some sort of gesture or touch event that I just can't capture in an overlay. Maybe the OS is doing something special, to my annoyance, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong somewhere that I haven't discovered yet.